# Choroplethr error message

Tags: r, acs, choropleth, census, choroplethr

I keep receiving this error message when attempting to use functions such as get_county_demographics or get_acs_data:

> Error in matrix(unlist(value, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE),
>   nrow = nr,  : 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'

Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: You should provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data that shows how you are calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for using choroplethr.

This error normally indicates that you have not set a Census API key. So the internal calls to get data from the Census API are returning NULL, and not real data.

Try the following:

1. Get a Census API key by going [here](http://api.census.gov/data/key_signup.html)
2. Type the following:

`library(acs); 
api.key.install('<your census api key>');`

Then try to run you code again.